# User.Identity.Name casing issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 along with the Oracle ASP.NET Membership Providers.  I'm running into a case sensitivity problem.

When a user logs into the system, it appears that the Membership provider sets the `User.Identity.Name` value to whatever the user typed in.  That is, if I created the user as `Foo` and the user logs in as `fOo` then everywhere where I use `User.Identity.Name` on my site, it'll show `fOo`.

Is there an easy way to work around this?  I tried

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).UserName;
```

but that gives me the exact same `fOo` value.

Comment: I think you've just found a provider-specific implementation detail. cdmckay's solution is the only way out I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a followup to cdmckay, if you'd want to have the User.Identity.Name correct as well, use

```
IIdentity newIdentity = new GenericIdentity(properlyCasedUser.UserName);
if (User is RolePrincipal)
    User = new RolePrincipal(((RolePrincipal)User).ProviderName, newIdentity, ((RolePrincipal)User).ToEncryptedTicket());
else
    User = new GenericPrincipal(newIdentity, null);
```

Comment: It seems silly that they don't just have a `.UserName = Foo` and a `.LoginUserName = fOo` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I found but I feel like it should be more direct than this:

```
MembershipUser user = _provider.GetUser(userName, false);
MembershipUser properlyCasedUser = _provider.GetUser(user.ProviderUserKey, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=104933 .. And this is from 2004, come on Microsoft... :-(